# Using CREATE SCHEMA AUTHORIZATION

Tags: database-schema, oracle18c

Can I use `CREATE SCHEMA AUTHORIZATION` for something other than the current user's schema?

I can do the following:

```
CREATE USER MAIN_USER 
IDENTIFIED BY main_user_pass;
GRANT CREATE SESSION TO MAIN_USER;
GRANT CREATE TABLE TO MAIN_USER;
ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA = MAIN_USER;
```

Query 1:

```
SELECT USER FROM DUAL;
```

Result 1:

```
SYS
```

Query 2:

```
SELECT sys_context( 'userenv', 'current_schema') FROM dual;
```

Result 2:

```
MAIN_USER
```

I can do this:

```
CREATE SCHEMA AUTHORIZATION SYS
   CREATE TABLE new_product 
      (color VARCHAR2(10)  PRIMARY KEY);
```

Result:

```
Schema AUTHORIZATION created.
```

But when I try to do this, an error appears:

```
CREATE SCHEMA AUTHORIZATION MAIN_USER
   CREATE TABLE new_product 
      (color VARCHAR2(10)  PRIMARY KEY);
```

Result:

```
ORA-02421: missing or invalid schema authorization identifier
02421. 00000 -  "missing or invalid schema authorization identifier"
*Cause:    the schema name is missing or is incorrect in an authorization
           clause of a create schema statement.
*Action:   If the name is present, it must be the same as the current
           schema.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I use CREATE SCHEMA AUTHORIZATION for something other than the current user's schema?

No, you can't. [The documentation says](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/CREATE-SCHEMA.html#GUID-2D154F9C-9E2B-4A09-B658-2EA5B99AC838):

> Use the CREATE SCHEMA statement to create multiple tables and views and perform multiple grants in your own schema in a single transaction.

> This statement lets you populate your schema ...

> Specify the name of the schema. The schema name must be the same as your Oracle Database username.

You have to be connected as the schema owner, so `user` returns `MAIN_USER`. Just changing your current schema with `ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA` is not sufficient.

---

It also says:

> To issue a CREATE SCHEMA statement, you must have the privileges necessary to issue the included statements.

and you have granted `CREATE TABLE` so that should work once you connect as that user. But it means you can't rely on the privileged `SYS` user's `CREATE ANY` privs to bypass the schema grants, which might have been an advantage had it been allowed to work as you hoped; if you want your user to end up without those privileges you'll have to grant them, run `CREATE SCHEMA` as that user, then revoke them again. Or go back to individual `CREATE object` statements, which you can run for another user as `SYS` - but without the all-or-nothing single-transaction benefit you get from `CREATE SCHEMA`.

Answer (score 2):

The error message is pretty clear: you can't do that. From the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/CREATE-SCHEMA.html#GUID-2D154F9C-9E2B-4A09-B658-2EA5B99AC838):

> The schema name must be the same as your Oracle Database username.

Setting `current_schema` only changes the default schema name prepended to an object reference in a SQL command that isn't fully qualified, so after setting it to `MAIN_USER`, this command:

```
select * table table_a;
```

would be interpreted as

```
select * from main_user.table_a;
```

instead of

```
select * from sys.table_a;
```

Setting `current_schema` doesn't actually change your logged in identity or affect your privileges in any way, and if `sys` can't execute a command like that against another schema then *nobody* can do it.